# Скрыть блок при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно скрыть блок при клике по элементу блока и вне этого элемента, сейчас блок скрывается почему то при первом клике и так и так а на втором клике скрывается только при клике по документу. Вот код :

```
 $('.in20 .hid').click(function(){
 var check = $(this).siblings('.hid-content').is(':visible')
$('.in20 .in19 .hid-content').each(function(){$(this).hide()})
  if(!check){
    $(this).siblings('.hid-content').show();
  } else {
   $(document).mouseup(e => {
  let ourBlock = $('.hid-content');
  if (!ourBlock.is(e.target) && ourBlock.has(e.target).length === 0)
      ourBlock.hide();
})

 }

 });




       <form method="get" action="" class="in20">
        {foreach $filters as $fid => $filter}
        <div class="in19">     <!---->
        {if $fid == 'price'}
            <div class=" ">  <!--in16-->
            {$c = $wa->shop->currency(true)}
    <div class="in17 hid"><b>[`Price`] <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></b></div>
  <div class="hid-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="flex-prices slider">
          [`from`] <input type="text" class="min" name="price_min" {if $wa->get('price_min')}value="{(int)$wa->get('price_min')}"{/if} placeholder="{floor($filter.min)}">
           [`to`] <input type="text" class="max" name="price_max"  {if $wa->get('price_max')}value="{(int)$wa->get('price_max')}"{/if} placeholder="{ceil($filter.max)}">{*{$c.sign} *} </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        {else}
            <div class=""> <!--in18-->
            <div class="in17 hid"><b>{$filter.name|escape} <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></b></div>
            <div class="hid-content" style="display:none;">
            <span style="display: none">{$filter.values|asort}</span>
            {foreach $filter.values as $v_id => $v}
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$filter.code}[]" {if in_array($v_id, (array)$wa->get($filter.code, array()))}checked{/if} value="{$v_id}"> {$v}
                </label>
            {/foreach}
            </div>
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: Добавьте HTML, пожалуйста, так проблема будет более менее явной

Comment: Добавил html, ниже.